# Как автоматически скроллить QScrollArea вниз?

Tags: python, pyqt, сигналы-слоты, qlabel, qscrollarea

Есть `QScrollArea`, к нему привязан `QLabel` (если есть способ с `QTextEdit` и т.д., то не принципиально).

Необходимо сделать некий эффект консоли, когда появляется новая строка, автоматически  скролится вниз, чтобы эту строку увидеть.

Пробовал гуглить как на русском, так и на английском. Хоть подобные темы и были найдены (на английском), методы и решения оттуда не помогли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из способов может быть использование сигнала `rangeChanged` вертикальная полоса прокрутки и, при необходимости, смещение его вниз, например:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.maxStart = 0
        self.i = 25

        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.widget)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scrollArea)

        self._vbar = self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar()  
        # испускается, когда диапазон значений полосы прокрутки изменился.
        self._vbar.rangeChanged.connect(self.scroll_to_end)                    # <<<=====
        self._scroll_items = 0

        for i in range(25):
            w = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
            layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(w)
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(f"loop {i}")
            layout.addWidget(label)
            self.layout.addWidget(label)

        self._timer = QtCore.QTimer(self, interval=1000)
        self._timer.timeout.connect(self.addLabel)
        self._timer.start()

    def addLabel(self):
        w = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(w)
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel(f"loop {self.i}")
        layout.addWidget(label)
        self.layout.addWidget(label)
        self.i += 1

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int , int)
    def scroll_to_end(self, _min, _max):
        items = self.layout.count()
        if self.maxStart != _max:        
            self._vbar.setValue(_max)  
        self._scroll_items = items


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = Main()
    m.resize(700, 600)
    m.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]